# php function that has a definable function when called

Tags: php, function, class

How do I compose a function with a section that is able to be defined when the function is called?

```
<?php
class MyClass {
        function doSomething() {
        $conn = $this->connectToDatabase("database");
        $rows = $conn->query($query);

        if ($rows->num_rows > 0) {  
            while($row = $rows->fetch_assoc()) {
                $col_value = $row['name'];
                function defineMe() {
                   //i need to be defined when called
                }
}
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }   

        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

That way, say I wanted to pull data from a database, I can change defineMe() to match the layout of the info that its spitting out.  How can I override this function and still access the data from the doSomething() function?

Like

```
$myClass = new MyClass;
$myClass->doSomething(){
    function defineMe() {
       echo $col_value;
    }
};
```

Comment: So what are you looking for defineMe() to do exactly... just echo the 'name' returned from your database query?

Comment: no, a div style layout, with multiple column values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass a callback to your function:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    function doSomething(callable $callback)
    {
        $conn = $this->connectToDatabase("database");
        $rows = $conn->query($query);

        if ($rows->num_rows > 0)
        {  
            while($row = $rows->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $col_value = $row['name'];
                $callback($col_value);      // Call callback
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }   

        $conn->close();
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass;
$myClass->doSomething(function($col_value) {
    echo "Inside callback: ".$col_value;
});
?>
```

Comment: You can also declare a callable type in your function definition (`doSomething(Callable $callback)`) rather than doing the `is_callable` check. (With PHP 7.)

Comment: Left it out on purpose for exactly that reason, not everyone is on PHP7 yet. But it is noteworthy indeed, in case OP (or somebody else coming by) is using PHP7. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, the `callable` type-hint is available since PHP 5.4 ([Link](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)), edited answer to simple use that.

Comment: It's true, but handling the error will need to be done a bit differently with PHP 5.